# Making a list of most popular searched phrases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've made an app where users can search articles from search box and now I would like to make some list to see which are the most popular searched phrases/words. What would be the most convenient solution to this.

The only thing I can think about is to make it simple like this:

```
create_table "searches", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "phrase"
  t.integer  "count"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

So each time when user types a word I go through a list of previous searches of all users and if I find a word, counter is increased by one. If I don't find a phrase, it's added to a table with value of count=1.\

The problem is that this looks inefficient to me because for simple word like "car" user can type many different variations like "blue car", "red car", "BMW car" etc. With increase of users list would grow exponentially and it would be really slow to go through whole list to find certain phrase and increase that counter.

Any ideas how to deal with this problem?

Comment: Here is a great video on how to create search using tags. http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging?view=asciicast I think it is a great starting point. Since most search needs tokenization of strings in the first place.

Comment: i have a suggestion, dont know how far it suites you...we have something called as `data-list` in html5 that we can create on form fields. This doesnt exactly suite your requirements, but you can mention your most prefered searches using it. `http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp`

Answer (score 0):

**Redis**

You'll be best using a third-party semi-persistent data store; typically [`Redis`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redis) to sort this out

Basically, when you get a search request on your app, you should let the action do two things:

> 1. Use a search facility (either ping the db directly, or use something like Solr)
> 2. Send the query string & date to Redis

Redis is a `key / value` data pair store; meaning it will give you the ability to keep simple bits of data stored for future use. Typical cases of Redis include the likes of storing voting patterns (for a site like SO), storing user follows (on a social network), and storing cumulative views, etc.

The reason you should look into it is because instead of putting heavy reliance on your database, providing a third party resource to store smaller chunks of data will make your app more [modular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming), and consequently, more efficient

-

**Search**

Your questions regarding the specification of the search terms will best be answered by using some sort of association (maybe referencing the `tag` list in the comments)

If you let all the search terms go through "naked" (I.E without any pre-association), you will likely get a mix of random data. A better way would be to "group" the data somehow. I don't have any experience of this, but I'd use `Redis` to store the search terms, and then work to `group` them before inserting into your DB